# What is my best option to evaluate a predictive (or proxy) variable?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, model-evaluation, roc, meteorology

I have a list of thunder flashes, and I'm trying to find if a meteorological variable (CAPE) is a good predictable variable (or proxy) for theses flashes. In my thoughts, I want to evaluate this proxy and find the best threshold (for example 1000 J/kg-1 is maybe the threshold where I have the best score).

My actual methodology is very simple for now:
I look at, for every hour of everyday, the value of CAPE variable, and I look if there is a thunder flash at the same time.
So in my mind:

- if CAPE value is > threshold and there is a thunder flash, then I have a hit
- if CAPE value is > threshold but no flashes, then false negative
- if CAPE < threshold but thunder flashes then false positive
- if CAPE < threshold but no flashes then true negative

I originally thought I can do it with ROC/AUC (see thread here : [Make ROC graph with my problematic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/574420/make-roc-graph-with-my-problematic?noredirect=1&lq=1)) but it seems it's not possible for my case.

What is the best tool I can use to evaluate this proxy as predictable variable ?

Comment: Why not use something like a logistic regression to find the probability of a thunder flash conditioned on the CAPE?

Comment: Thanks Demetri. Have you an example to give me ? I'm not familiar with statistics, but i learn quickly. I'm working in python.

Comment: The internet is filled with examples, I'd suggest you perhaps try googling a logistic regression tutorial.